# laravel api gate check

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

im using laravel 7
and im using gates and policies
i have api controller called `Journal_entries_controller`
and i have `index function`

```
public function index()
{
    $journal_entries = Journal_entry::with('get_journal_entry_lines')->get();
    return response()->json($journal_entries,200);
}
```

like this everything working so good ..
to check gate i did this ..

```
public function index()
{
    $auth = auth('api')->user();
    if(!Gate::allows('journal_entries.view',$auth))
        return 'not auth';
    $journal_entries = Journal_entry::with('get_journal_entry_lines')->get();
    return response()->json($journal_entries,200);
}
```

like that i get not auth the code stop there
and if i dd($auth) i gat the logged user like this ..

```
public function index()
{
    $auth = auth('api')->user();
    dd($auth);
}
```

any help here thanks ..

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: the gate function now working inside api controller with me

Comment: Ok, are you getting errors? Any log files you can share?

Comment: i get the return not auth

Comment: the authorization system already uses the currently authenticated user (the first argument passed to any gate you define), but what is your 'gate' that you defined doing?

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport or Sanctum? Also, please share your route definition.

Comment: no im not using passport or sanctum

Comment: `auth('api')` this is basic auth or `token` based .?

Comment: token based....

Comment: Making a wild guess here, do you have `Gate::define('journal_entries.view', function (User $user) {// your logic here);});` in your `AuthServiceProvider` ? In this case, you wouldn't need to pass the $auth to the Gate, but in case if you really need the $auth in your Gate, you will need to define your Gate as `Gate::define('journal_entries.view', function (User $user, $auth) {// your logic with $auth here);});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if statement:

```
if(!Gate::allows('journal_entries.view',$auth))
    return 'not auth';
```

The `Gate::allows` is returning `false` by adding the `!` we make the response `true` which is why the `not auth` code is returning.

The first thing to do is make sure the `journal_entries.view` is a gate in the `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`.

If it is a valid gate please post the contents of the gate so we know the intended functionality.

In the mean time you may want to try changing
`if(!Gate::allows('journal_entries.view',$auth))` to `if(Gate::denies('journal_entries.view',$auth))` or
`if(Gate::allows('journal_entries.view',$auth))`

The docs for gates can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates